# Handling similar functionality but from different page origins in a Django Ajax web app

Tags: ajax, django, django-views, prototypejs

I'm using Django and prototype.js for an Ajax-style web application. I have already some experience but am still a newbie in web programming stuff in general.

I have designed my web application to behave like this (which i think is straight-forward):

The HTML page is composed of multiple div-elements that represent different modules of interaction with the user. There are links which point to Javascript functions ("onclick") which in turn call the Django server framework via Ajax requests. This executes view-methods in the Django-framework which do some functional stuff (change data in the database) and then finally update the relevant section (div) of the page where the user has clicked the link.

So far so good.

Now the issue is that i find myself confronted with the fact that different links in different sections should do the same functional stuff, but should update different divs as a function on where they have been called from.

Example:
I have a section or page A where there is a list of all orders of a user.
There should be a link to cancel the order next to it.
Clicking it should cancel the order (functional stuff), then update the list of orders in page A.

There is another page B where i have a list of orders for a specific field.
Again it should be possible to cancel by clicking on a link.
It should do the same functional stuff as above, but now update the page B with the orders by field list.

I wonder how to factor the common functional stuff.

The naive approach is to have 
page A link -> onclick(cancelOrderA) -> js:cancelOrderA() -> Ajax request to url/cancelOrderA -> Django view function A -> render new page A
page B link -> onclick(cancelOrderB) -> js:cancelOrderB() -> Ajax request to url/cancelOrderB -> Django view function B -> render new page B

So i find myself writing all those functions (javascript and Django views) allthough it does the same functional code.

Of course i can write a python function that encapsulates the common functional code.
But i have the feeling i still need all the different glue functions from above.
Do i need a dedicated Django-url and -view for each action?
Do i need a dedicated Javascript function for each action?

Do i have a misunderstanding here?
How do you guys handle that kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

Can you abstract your calling javascript function and your view to be more generic?

E.g.

```
// before
var cancelOrderA = function(...) {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/to/cancelOrderA',
        data: { ... },
        },
});

var cancelOrderB = function(...) {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/to/cancelOrderB',
        data: { ... },
        },
});
```

...becomes:

```
var cancelOrder = function(order_type, ...) {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/path/to/cancelOrder',
        data: {'type': order_type, ... },
        },
});

// ...

cancelOrder('Application', ...);
```

So now in your back-end Django view you have a string parameter to use that you didn't have before...

```
# views.py
from django.db.models.loading import get_model

def cancel_object(request):
    model_type = request.POST['order_type']  # e.g. "Application"
    id = request.POST['id']

    get_model('myApp', model_type).get(id=int(id)).cancel()

    return HttpResponse(...)
```

Comment: I think you didn't get what i was trying to say. Actually the order type is the same for both. Exactly the same functionality should executed for both. Only difference is they must produce a different HttpResponse each, as they have been called from different parts of the page and thus need to Ajax-replace different divs.